# space complexity of DFA intersection problem

Tags: reference-request, complexity-classes, space-complexity, lower-bounds, dfa

the DFA-intersection computation problem, given two DFAs specified on the input, compute the intersection DFA, or the decision problem to determine its emptiness, turns out to have wider/ deeper significance in computational complexity theory.[1][2] it is O(n<sup>2</sup>) time with no better lower bounds known, and tight bounds possibly having major implications on multiple complexity class separations. looking for insight/ refs.

> what is the best known *space* complexity of determining DFA intersection (emptiness)? how does the best known algorithm work?

[1] [Deciding emptiness of intersection of regular languages in subquadratic time](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29142/deciding-emptiness-of-intersection-of-regular-languages-in-subquadratic-time) / cstheory SE
[2] [Two DFA intersection emptiness connections to SETH & L vs P](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/33010/two-dfa-intersection-emptiness-connections-to-seth-l-vs-p) / cstheory SE

Comment: There is a difference between computing the product DFA and determining if the intersection is empty.  For computing the product DFA, take a look at: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/152/dfa-intersection-in-subquadratic-space

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solving intersection Non-Emptiness for 2 DFA's:**

It essentially just becomes a reachability problem for the [product DFA](https://www.quora.com/Deterministic-finite-automata-intersection-and-union-How-do-I-use-product-construction).

- Roughly, we can solve it deterministically in $O(n^2)$ time using $O(n^2)$ space.
- Or, we can solve it non-deterministically with $O(\log(n))$ space.
- By [Savitch's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch%27s_theorem), we can also solve it deterministically in $2^{O(\log^2(n))}$ time using $O(\log^2(n))$ space.

To the best of my knowledge, it is not known if we can solve it deterministically in polynomial time using $O(n^{2-\epsilon})$ space.

Feel free to share any thoughts or ideas in the comments.  :)